# Get DataGridView checkbox value after changed

Tags: c#, datagridview

i have `DataGridView` with several columns, every Row represent my object with several properties like name, id etc.
after change my `Name column` `Checkbox` i want to update my object
How can i get my column `Checknox` state ?
This is what i have try:

```
private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}

private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Name")
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `Name` is the name of `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Name")
    {
        var isChecked = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value as bool? ?? false;
        //rest of logic
    }
}
```

this is the simplest and safest way.

To iterate through all cells in row use this code:

```
DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
{
   object value = cell.Value;
}
```

Comment: That works fine, and how can i get the values of each column from row ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the `FindControl()` to get the state of checkbox:

```
CheckBox cbName = (CheckBox)dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].FindControl("cbName");
checkState = cbName.CheckState.toString();
```

or

```
isChecked = cbName.Checked;
```